# java store data on one array variable and call it afterwards

Tags: java, arrays

I am quite new to programming and I am having a difficult time figuring out a certain problem.

I'm having an "Add Order" function in my basic POS java project but once I add another order from another list, the only thing that shows in the receipt is the last one I ordered.

So here's just a SAMPLE of my code:

```
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Your order(s): ");
            System.out.println(order+" x "+howmany+" = P "+tempBill);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

            // STORE IN A HOLDER VARIABLE IN CASE OF ADDING ORDERS
            ordery[i2] = order;
            tempBilly[i2] = tempBill;
            howmanyarray[i2] = howmany;
            i2++;

            // CHOOSING IF ADD MORE ORDER OR PROCEED TO PAYMENT

            System.out.println("What do you wish to do after this?");
            System.out.println("[1] Add Order\n[2] Proceed to Payment\n[3] Cancel ");

            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
                choice2 = input.nextInt();
                if (choice2==1) {
                    readMain();
                }
                else if (choice2==2)
                {
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("ITEM(S) ORDERED: ");
                    for (a = 1; a < i2; a++) {
                        System.out.println(ordery[a]+" x "+howmanyarray[a]+" = P "+tempBilly[a]);
                        totalBill = totalBill + tempBilly[a];
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    do
                    {
                        System.out.print("Enter amount of cash for payment: ");
                        cash = input.nextDouble();
                        if (cash>=totalBill) {
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxx OFFICIAL RECEIPT xxxxxxxxx");
                            System.out.println("ORDER(S):");
                            System.out.println(" • "+order+" x "+howmany);
                            System.out.println("TOTAL BILL: P "+totalBill);
                            System.out.println("AMOUNT PAID: P "+cash);
                            System.out.println("CHANGE: P "+bills.change(cash, totalBill));

                            PrintWriter resibo = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("resibo.txt", true));
                            Date dt = new Date();
                            resibo.write("xxxxxxxxx OFFICIAL RECEIPT xxxxxxxxx\n");
                            resibo.write(dt.toString());
                            resibo.write("\nORDER(S):\n");
                            resibo.write(" • "+order+" x "+howmany+"\n");
                            resibo.write("TOTAL BILL: P "+totalBill+"\n");
                            resibo.write("AMOUNT PAID: P "+cash+"\n");
                            resibo.write("CHANGE: P "+bills.change(cash, totalBill));
                            resibo.write("\n\n");
                            resibo.close();

                            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("THANK YOU! PLEASE COME AGAIN!");
                            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println();
                            read.close();

                            String[] str = null;
                            try2.main(str);
                        }
                    }
                    while (cash<totalBill || cash<0);
                }
                else if (choice2==3){
                    try2.customer();
                }
            }
            while (choice2>3 || choice2<=0);
```

Here's an image of the sample output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGI7B.jpg)

I tried ordering a smoothie from the drinks list then proceed to payment and after paying the receipt should show the two items I ordered but it only shows the last one I ordered (the smoothie). here's the image or the receipt: [receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elKMu.jpg)

Kindly help me please. Thank you.

Comment: What output you are getting ?

Comment: @iamkezyang The problem lies in the other half of your codes (which is not shown here).

Comment: suppose I ordered another from the drinks (eg. strawberry smoothie), but once it prints the receipt, only the smoothie shows from the order list. it supposed to be also showing my 1st order which is the oreo cheesecake

Comment: Put more code to make the problem reproducable.

Comment: please check the code again, i have added a few more

Comment: Why did you delete the image?

Comment: can you post the whole program ? or impl of `readMain` method

Comment: public static void readMain() throws IOException {
  System.out.println("Choose a list to view");
  System.out.println("[1] Cakes & Desserts\n[2] Drinks\n[3] Cancel");
  do
  {
   System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
   choice = input.nextInt();
   if (choice==1) {
    readCD();
   }
   else if(choice==2) {
    readDrinks();
   }
   else if(choice==3) {
    try2.customer();
   }
  }
  while (choice>3||choice<=0);
 }